# Why is this call not passing the information from my xml file to the winForm?

Tags: c#, xml, code-reuse

I'm a NEWB and I'm lost. I beg your patience.

I have a working application where I believe I am serializing (??) xml file data using the following code.

```
    public static string elementUser(object sender)
    {
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();

        //**EDIT:** This is where I would call 
        //locateFolder(sender, xmldoc);
        //instead of fileExistsRequest(xmldoc);

        fileExistsRequest(xmldoc);

        XmlNodeList nodelist = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//Name");

        foreach (XmlNode xmlnode in nodelist)
        {
            if (xmlnode["User"] != null)
            {
                usertxt = xmlnode["User"].InnerText;                
            }

            else
            {
            }
            return usertxt;
        }
        return usertxt;            
    }
```

After calling this I load the contents of the xml element in a winForm for display to the user to manipulate. Other forms will call other elements. Ex Math.cs will call only `<Start>` `<End>` or `<Ticks>` for use in other dialogs.

The above was designed to work on one xml file with one entry (??) which looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SubmitTime12>
  <Name Key="11/18/2014">
    <User>fpytel</User>
    <Date>11/18/2014</Date>
    <JobNum>00000</JobNum>
    <RevNum>CR8</RevNum>
    <Task>why</Task>
    <Start>00:00 AM</Start>
    <End>8:00 AM</End>
    <Ticks></Ticks>
    <Explanation>Expletives Abound</Explanation>
  </Name>
</SubmitTime12>
```

It occurred to me that I could use `elementUser(object sender)` to load other xml files with the same basic format, but with more entries. Really the only change would be that the `<User>` is not included in the `Reportfpytel.xml` file entries as the user is part of the file name. Ex:

```
...
<Name Key="11/14/2014 6:45:57 AM">
  <Date>11/3/2014</Date>
  <JobNum>00000</JobNum>
  <RevNum>00000</RevNum>
  <Task>Testing less</Task>
  <Start>4:00 AM</Start>
  <End>4:00 AM</End>
  <TotalTime></TotalTime>
</Name>
<Name Key="11/14/2014 6:46:39 AM">
  <Date>11/13/2014</Date>
  <JobNum>26356</JobNum>
  <RevNum>00000</RevNum>
  <Task>Red Lines</Task>
  <Start>2:00 AM</Start>
  <End>2:00 AM</End>
  <TotalTime></TotalTime>
</Name>
...
```

So in the first code above I replaced `fileExistsRequest(xmldoc);` with the following call by creating it in the `elementUser(object sender);` and refactoring it out of the code. This is what was supplied by VS2010.

```
    public static void locateFolder(object sender, XmlDocument xmldoc)
    {
        string senderName = sender.ToString();
        if (senderName == "Start")
        {

        }
        else if (senderName.Contains("ApproveTime"))
        {
            fileExistsRequest(xmldoc);
        }
        else if (senderName.Contains("Report"))
        {
            fileExistsReport(xmldoc);
        }
        else if (senderName == "Math")
        {
            fileExistsReport(xmldoc);
        }
    }
```

This works without error but will not load the elements to the controls on the calling form. I stepped through every line from the time it is called (either onLoad or onShown) and it finds the folder, finds the file, finds the element, assigns the element to a string and gets ready to feed the string to the control on the calling form. When I take the final step to bring it to the form it clears the string to "" and shows the calling form with blank fields.

If I put a break in the `locateFolder(object sender, XmlDocument xmldoc)` function and try to step past this

```
        string senderName = sender.ToString();
```

I get a NullReferenceException error with tips `new` keyword and checking if the object is null. That's the only error I can find that is giving me a hint. Almost like it's loading the strings into the controls and then emptying the contents again. What I don't understand is why it works just fine without the `locateFolder()` call and why no error is thrown when I do not place a break in the code to try to find the error. Like I said, I have made that call on the `Shown` event as well as the `Load` event.

Is there anyone that understands what's going on here. I really would like to reuse this code.

**EDIT2:** Modified per JTMon to try to catch the null exception. It ran right past it. Did I have it configured correctly??

```
    public static void locateFolder(object sender, XmlDocument xmldoc)
    {
        //XmlDocument xmldoc1 = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            string senderName = sender.ToString();
            if (senderName == "Start")
            {

            }
            //...OriginalCode
        }
        catch
        {
            if (sender == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("returned null");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if(sender == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("returned null");
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT3** Per Galdo I changed the code to this.

```
    public static void locateFolder(object sender, XmlDocument xmldoc)
    {
        if (sender != null)
        {
            string senderName = sender.ToString();
            if (senderName == "Start")
            {

            } 
         //...OriginalCode
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("returned Null");
        }
    }
```

My error has cleared up. Both JTMon's and Galdo's suggestion has cleared the error, but it is still not passing the values to the sender form textbox.

Thank you all very much for commenting. I'm trying to keep up. Thanks!!

**EDIT4** Per request from Kristof. The call from the sender of `elementUser();`

```
    private void ApproveTime_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Start p = (Start)this.Owner;
        Control[] c = p.Controls.Find("bApproveTime", false);
        Button b = (Button)c[0];
        b.Enabled = false;


        WidgetLogic.elementUser(this);
    }
```

Comment: Can we see the code where you call locateFolder?

Comment: @Galdo Yes I'm sorry. I added a commented out section to the code. It's where I would call `fileExistsRequest(xmldoc);`. Instead I call `locateFolder();` Thank You for commenting!!

Comment: did you check to see if sender is actually== null? I don't see it initialized anywhere in your code and the fileExistsRequest method does not use it while locatefoder does.

Comment: @JTMon When sender==null I can't actually catch it. I tried to put it into a Try{}Catch{} but that didn't even catch it. It just runs through and completes the code without a break. I'm sure it's null only because it throws a runtime error?? The dialog box from VS2010 that says 'Hey dummy. You're not doing it right' I can step through the code though and it is returning sender, which I'm trying to use the FormName or some part of it as shown in the code `locateFolder()`

Comment: @JTMon If I put it in a Try{}Catch{}Finally{} would the Finally{} catch it? I'll try to reconfigure it real quick. If you know that would be awesome

Comment: @JTMon Didn't work. Please see EDIT2

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault No Joy. Thanks for responding. Any Ideas?? I Really Really would appreciate it. :-D Please Please??

Comment: Ok... You don't need a try catch here... Just check if sender is null in your method. 

    public static void locateFolder(object sender, XmlDocument xmldoc)
    {
      if (sender != null) {
       //your code
      }
      else {
       //code if sender is null
      }

PS : when you do a try catch, you must actually catch something... check on google for examples.

Comment: @Galdo I'll try that and google it now. Processing....

Comment: What you are saying sounds impossible :) While you are debugging your code throws an exception on sender.ToString() but it doesn't jump inside the catch block? If that's the case it sounds like your code isn't getting compiled and you might be debugging old code. Try manually wiping your bin & obj folders and try again please :)

Comment: So sender might not be null.... what value does it have in it? maybe it is not evaluating to any of the values you are expecting and therefore not going into any of the if statements.

Comment: @JTMon I just tried Galdo's suggestion. it is definitely not returning null. It is returning the sender. In this case it returns the `sender.Name` (It says the name of the form anyway) which is accessed using `sender.toString();`. I am definitely looking for the name of the form as the sender. It's not a button click. It's definitely going into the statements and finding the correct information. I can step through it and see what it's doing.

Comment: @Kristof Interestingly enough I tried Galdo's code and the `Try{}`. I just noticed that it does not throw an error in either case. It steps through as originally noted and does as I explained above, excepting it does not throw the error and just as it enters the form supply the information to the textbox it reverts to ""

Comment: @Galdo I tried your suggestion. It actually stops throwing the error. It does not solve my problem though. It still supplies a blank value to the sending form textbox. Thank You VERY much for helping me clear the error though. I really appreciate it!! :-D

Comment: @FrankPytel maybe i'm not following completely, what code is calling elementUser? And am i correct to assume that you sender is null but you do not see a messagebox with value returned null? Are you using any multi treading?

Comment: @Kristof No I am not using multi threading. `elementUser()` is being called by the sender. In every case the sender is the form and is making the call from either `Load` or `Shown` events of the winForm. This in turn sets the initial value of the form (onLoad) or repopulates the form when the user interacts with it (onShown). The sender is absolutely not null. Please see EDIT3 or EDIT2. That error is resolved, but if you have any insight as to why?? That would be awesome!! The `MessageBox.Show();` is not being hit because the test is `if(sender!=null){}`

Comment: Could you give me an example of what sender is containing?(can't find it in your question wall of text :) ). Also : during form load you(or generated code?) is calling the elementUser object. Could you copy & paste that line here as well please.(also can't find it in your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally getting to something that might be a solution to your problem.
The "this" in this line of code :

```
WidgetLogic.elementUser(this);
```

is the class that contains the void ApproveTime_Load.
I'm hoping that class is a form.(if not please specify the class)
The problem with your code is that you're passing this into the function elementUser as an object and later on casting it as a string.
Could you pass a string into this function instead of an object?
Assuming "this" is a form it should look like this :

```
WidgetLogic.elementUser(this.Text);
```

You could then refactor your elementUser and following functions to not take a sender object but a sender string(which makes a bit more sense).
The word sender is usually used as an object because you pass the calling button or form.
You could still pass the actual sender but then you can just do toString. You'd have to cast the sender object to a form and get the Text property.

Comment: Well, I'll be testing this for a while and it makes no sense. This edit actually returns null from the else{}, but it works. :-O I didn't want to hold you up but it looks like you've found the answer Kristof!! I'll let you know. I'll likely be testing this for a minute. Thank You!!

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure i fully understand your case so just lemme know if anything is off and we'll steer from there. Heading home for now though, expect me back in like 16 hours ;)

Comment: Have an Awesome evening Kristof. 5 hours to go!! :-D

Comment: I've reverted back to an earlier stage. I had so many errors I don't think I could possibly track them all down. They weren't errors thrown at debug or build or runtime. Other parts of the application just quit functioning entirely. I'm not sure what was happening. For the moment I need to finish writing what I have because I have to get it out. Management later could be a bit of a pain, but such is the price. Thank You again Kristof. I've book marked this. I intend to come back to it in the future. Thank You Thank You so much!! :-D Have a Great Day

Comment: Okay, good luck refactoring! Poke me if you need me again *flies away*